# SMTP session transcript explanation

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am running POSTFIX mail server to manage a very simple mail server. I am getting some error logs like this

```
 Out: 220 mail.myserver.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
 In:  EHLO mail179-29.suw41.mandrillapp.com
 Out: 250-mail.myserver.com
 Out: 250-PIPELINING
 Out: 250-SIZE 10240000
 Out: 250-VRFY
 Out: 250-ETRN
 Out: 250-STARTTLS
 Out: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
 Out: 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
 Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 Out: 250-8BITMIME
 Out: 250 DSN
 In:  STARTTLS
 Out: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
 In:  EHLO mail179-29.suw41.mandrillapp.com
 Out: 250-mail.myserver.com
 Out: 250-PIPELINING
 Out: 250-SIZE 10240000
 Out: 250-VRFY
 Out: 250-ETRN
 Out: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
 Out: 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
 Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 Out: 250-8BITMIME
 Out: 250 DSN
 In:  MAIL
     FROM:<bounce-md_30935315.59e11c20.v1-dd2701d3e6ff46eda1fb636f48bb42b3@mandrillapp.com>
     BODY=8BITMIME
 Out: 452 4.3.1 Insufficient system storage
 In:  QUIT
 Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

I am having some hard time understanding what is going on. I know this means my server is running out of space. But is this session an indicator that I have other problems? Is this just a legitimate mail delivery try that failed because I have no space? or it is meaning someone is trying to send something out of my server?

Also is there an easy way to stop such spammers from storming my server with this undesired mail?

Any help or pointing to resources is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information that you have posted there is no indication that you have any other problem than insufficient disk space.

The `SMTP` session is a valid one that aborts when your server generates the temporary error.

Most real mailservers will follow the `SMTP` standards andqueue the email message  and retry delivery, at increasingly longer intervals between unsuccessful delivery attempts , until either your temporary error is gone and the message is delivered or they  reach the maximum number of unsuccessful attempts and trigger an error and bounce message to the original sender.

therefore multiple unsuccessful attempts from the same sender is not the behavior of spammers, rather exactly how real mailservers are supposed to behave to ensure reliable delivery.

Fix the disk space issue so your server can accept the message, configure and install grey listing and a spam filter etc to deal with actual spam